# How to introduce pre-specified random variation into a continuous variable in R?

Tags: r, random, dplyr, data-cleaning, variance

I've been asked to "simulate" random variations into a set of continuous biomarkers, to see which of them are more robust to possible analytical variations.

Let's say we have the initial values of `biomk`:

```
df = structure(list(biomk = c(4.97673374242057, 4.9600435079802, 4.73707525686803, 
            4.6737629774537, 5.12038615805537, 5.16421438202456, 5.94437293957413, 
            5.33464929579543, 5.12871458216186, 4.50424426739813)), row.names = c(NA, 
            -10L), class = "data.frame")
    
        
> df
          biomk
    1  4.976734
    2  4.960044
    3  4.737075
    4  4.673763
    5  5.120386
    6  5.164214
    7  5.944373
    8  5.334649
    9  5.128715
    10 4.504244
```

Let's say we want 15% of variation in `biomk_15`. The person doing this before me had coded:

```
set.seed(20)
seq_15 <- seq(from=-15, to=15, by=.01)
df$factor15<-sample(seq_15, size=10, replace=TRUE)
df$biomk15 <- df$biomk+((df$factor15*df$biomk)/100)
    
> df
          biomk factor15  biomk15
    1  4.976734   -13.35 4.312340
    2  4.960044    -2.86 4.818186
    3  4.737075     3.98 4.925611
    4  4.673763     4.11 4.865855
    5  5.120386     1.65 5.204873
    6  5.164214    13.08 5.839694
    7  5.944373     3.89 6.175609
    8  5.334649    -9.60 4.822523
    9  5.128715    -5.11 4.866637
    10 4.504244     3.36 4.655587
```

This is a simple approach to simulate some random variations.

But this comes from an idea to simulate some sort of "inter-assay" coefficient of variance (CV), calculated as sd/mean. But the issue with this approach is how it is limited to a (-15,+15) range and ignores the initial "intra-assay" CV:

```
 # Original biomk CV
> (sd(df$biomk)/mean(df$biomk))
[1] 0.07956928
 # New biomk CV
> (sd(df$biomk15)/mean(df$biomk15))
[1] 0.1105335
```

Of course, ideally this CV simulations should not be done in silico but with inter-lab data etc etc, but I have to do this.

**QUESTION: Do you see a way that this could be done better? Or to actually base these new variations so we obtain, in this case e.g., 15% of random change in the new CV?**

I'm not sure if it makes sense, but thanks anyway.

Comment: "Let's say we want 15% of variation in biomk_15." I assume you mean add 15 % variation (increase the CV by 15 %)? 1. Your code doesn't do that. 2. The CV can't stay the same if you add variation. Your specs are not well-defined.

Comment: Yeah you are correct. I'll edit it. And yeah, the code doesn't do that, I've been just passed this code and this task and noticed it is strange. Changing the CV in 15% would be the goal I guess

Comment: I'm still unsure what the goal is but something like `df$biomk15 <- df$biomk + rnorm(nrow(df), mean = 0, sd = 0.15 * mean(df$biomk))` comes to mind. Change the distribution as required. (Note that CV is defined as SD / mean. Your definition is strange.)